How to Add White Sheet Page and Template to Altium PCB Doc?
I want to add this kind of white sheet page to my PCB layout.
Can anyone can help me with this? There is no option sheet template for PCB.


Don't. This kind of information in the PCB and Gerber files is a relic from ancient times. You can easily generate proper drill tables, dimensions, layer stacks... in Altium. They call the tool Draftsman.

Go to properties then General then Sheet Setting and add dimensions.
